# Error while trying to display images from FirebaseFirestore using picasso

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel, picasso

I am trying to display images and text from firebasefirestore.The text is displayed well but I am stuck trying to display the images. What is the correct way to display the images because it seems the tutorial i was following is not spot on or either am missing something
I tried looking on some answers but didnot really get enough help
Below is my main activity and Model classes

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.tutorscape;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mFirebaseList;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mFirebaseList= findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Admin");


        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                .setQuery(query,Model.class)
                .build();
         adapter= new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
               View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {


                 holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
                 holder.list_title.setText(model.getTitle());
              //  Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(imageView);


             }
        };


        mFirebaseList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFirebaseList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirebaseList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView list_name;
        private TextView list_title;
      //  private ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            list_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            list_title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
       //     imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
package com.example.tutorscape;

public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String title;

    private String image;
    private Model(){}

    public Model(String name, String title,String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.image=image;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

The urls of the images open well in the browser

Comment: Please accept the answer that gave the solution, in this way, other community members can identify easily the solution to the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment everything & remove imageView to holder.imageView in this
Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(imageView)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call `Picasso` as like this,

```
Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

It is just like calling `holder.list_name` to set the text.

Uncomment these line, it is correct.

```
private ImageView imageView;

imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Hope it works now!

Comment: I get the following error C:\Users\Shadreck\AndroidStudioProjects\TutorScape\app\src\main\java\com\example\tutorscape\MainActivity.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(imageView);
                                                          ^
  symbol: variable imageView

Comment: I hope now you got it!